# How do I make special characters (from a referenced page item) not error out a mailto button?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a dynamic action on a button that runs a small bit of javascript. Basically, it acts as a mailto link and adds some of the page items to the body of the email. it works for the most part but I have noticed that if the value of the page item contains an & the email cuts off at that point in the text. This is what I currently have:

```html
var policy_num = $v('P9_POLICY');
var tclose = $v('P9_TDATE');
var taskt = $v('P9_TYPE');
var taskd = $v('P9_DESC');
var audito = $v('P9_TASK_AUDIT_OUTCOME');
var auditc = $v('P9_NOTE');

location.href= "mailto:" +
   "?subject=" + "Please take immediate action" +
   "&body="+ 

"%0APolicy: " + policy_num +
"%0ATask Closed: " + tclose +
"%0ATask Type: " + taskt + 
"%0ATask Description: " + taskd + 
"%0AAudit Outcome: " + audito +
"%0AAudit Comment: " + auditc ;
```

If there is a better way to accomplish this kind of mailto function that I would definitely be open to that. This is just the first way I found that actually worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your Items contain an &-Character it will act as a control-character. You need to escape it so it won't be interpreted as a control-character anymore.

It should look something like this:

```
var policy_num = escape($v('P9_POLICY'));
var tclose = escape($v('P9_TDATE'));
var taskt = escape($v('P9_TYPE'));
var taskd = escape($v('P9_DESC'));
var audito = escape($v('P9_TASK_AUDIT_OUTCOME'));
var auditc = escape($v('P9_NOTE'));

location.href= "mailto:" +
   "?subject=" + "Please take immediate action" +
   "&body="+ 

"%0APolicy: " + policy_num +
"%0ATask Closed: " + tclose +
"%0ATask Type: " + taskt + 
"%0ATask Description: " + taskd + 
"%0AAudit Outcome: " + audito +
"%0AAudit Comment: " + auditc ;
```